# Limit sqlite db size on .Net Core

Tags: sqlite, .net-core

On a .Net Core 2.0 app I am trying to limit the size of my DB so that I don't exceed a specific size.
I've researched and I saw that Java has a method to limit the size but for C# I didn't find any such method. I did found that by checking the 
 Environment.SystemPageSize and modifying the SQLITE_MAX_PAGE_COUNT I can get exactly what I want. The problem is that I can't define SQLITE_MAX_PAGE_COUNT and I also want the change to apply only to my DB, I do not want to affect other DB sizes.

Is there any API that allows me to do this directly or a workaround? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [PRAGMA max_page_count](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_max_page_count) SQL command to limit the maximum number of pages in the database file.

Comment: Quick question. This solved my issue but there is a case when I want to change the DB size and I can see that I can only make it larger, not smaller. "Query or set the maximum number of pages in the database file. Both forms of the pragma return the maximum page count. The second form attempts to modify the maximum page count. The maximum page count cannot be reduced below the current database size." If I want to resize and make it smaller, is there other way than migrating the DB to another DB, deleting the current one and recreate it with the correct value? Thanks!